# Logic App - CurrentTime - how to select time only (hh:mm:ss)

Tags: azure-logic-apps

When using CurrentTime in logic apps, it gives the full date/time value like 2020-06-14T20:16:49.0131751Z

How can I select the time only Like 20:16:49?

The reason: I want to use CurrentTime in a condition to do actions within certain time windows.

For example: if time current time is greater than 08:00:00 & less that 23:00:00 --> do action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the [formatDateTime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatDateTime) function in logic app to format your `CurrentTime`, please refer to my logic app below:

[image]

The first expression(utcNow) is:

```
utcNow()
```

The second expression(formatDateTime) is:

```
formatDateTime(variables('CurrentTime'), 'HH:mm:ss')
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Hi Hury, thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to an api that provides the time. For example: http://worldclockapi.com/